# Can not add method OnModelCreating

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

This code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;


    namespace ArticleLibrary_.NET.Models
    {
        public class ArticleLibraryEntitiy : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {

      }

    }
```

gives an error saying:

```
Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
```

in line

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

and also it seems `ModelBuilder` is not recognized by VS code editor

Do I have to add any other reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to write the `OnModelCreating` function **in** the class. you write it under it. change your code to:

```
namespace ArticleLibrary_.NET.Models 
{ 
    public class ArticleLibraryEntitiy : DbContext 
    { 
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; } 
        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
        { 

        } 
    } 

}
```